# How can I identify a specific item in <select> and add a delete button each row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1.) I have created a nested table, then what I want to do is when I click the 'Delete' button inside the child table, its row will be deleted.

2.) I have `<select>` tag. The problem is how can I put a validation which checks if the item type has been already selected by one customer, but this selected item can be also selected at the next Customer.

For example, Customer1 selects `Iron`. Now the Customer1 cannot choose the `Iron` type of item on the next item. Customer1 may also select `Copper` or `Wood` but not `Iron`. Then if I have Customer2 the `Iron` type of Item can be selectable.

Here's my code:

```js
    $(".addItem").on('click', function(e) {
          $(this).closest('table').find(".item:last").after('<tr class="item"><td><button>Delete</button></td><td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="" id=""><option value="">Iron</option><option value="">Copper</option><option value="">Wood</option></select></td></tr>');
        });
    
    
        $(".addCustomer").on('click', function(e) {
          var newCustomer = $('.customer:last').after('<tr class="customer"><td>New Customer</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
          var newCart = $('.cart:first').clone(true, true).wrap('td');
          newCart.find('tbody').html("").html('<tr class="item"><td><button>Delete</button></td><td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="" id=""><option value="">Iron</option><option value="">Copper</option><option value="">Wood</option></select></td></tr>');
          $('.customer:last').append(newCart);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    
    
        $('.itemType').on('change', function() {
                
            var selected = $(this)find('option:selected').val();
    
            if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === selected) {
                alert("Item already selected.");
            }
            
        });
```

```css
 table,
        td,
        th {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
      <title>PO</title>

      <header>
        <form id="panel">
    
        </form>
      </header>
      <section id="I">
    
    
        <table id='PO1' class="purchaseOrder">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Cart</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
              <td>Some Name</td>
              <td>30</td>
              <td>My Address</td>
              <td>Male</td>
              <td>
                <table class='cart'>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                      <th>Brand</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                      <th>Size</th>
                      <th>Color</th>
                      <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr id='item1' class='item'>
                      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
                      <td>Yamaha</td>
                      <td>30</td>
                      <td>Large</td>
                      <td>Black</td>
                      <td>
                       <select name="" class="itemType">
                        <option value="i">Iron</option>
                        <option value="c">Copper</option>
                        <option value="w">Wood</option>
                       </select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan='5'></td>
                      <td>
                        <button class="addItem">Add Item</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
    
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan='3'></td>
              <td>
                <button class="addCustomer">Add Customer</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
    
    
      </section>
      <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
```

Comment: Inside your `$('.itemType').on('change', function() {` first line says `$(this)find(`, it should be `$(this).find(` .. is this a typo ?

Comment: In terms of validation, what will happen if more than three items added in the cart. As there is only three item types? when first three items have all the three items selected for each respectively, then what will be the selected one for fourth one?

Comment: I managed to handle it, can you check below?

Comment: @Aruna Our customers are counted, so if we have 3 customers then we only have 3 items :)  You're so great men, Im gonna test it.

Comment: @Webman yes please test and let me know if any changes required :-)

Comment: @Webman Instead of `alert`, I have disabled the option not allowing to select

Comment: @Aruna Its working men, and one more thing. What if I only have one row then the delete button should NOT be deletable.

Comment: @Webman This is done, please test

Comment: @Aruna You're so great dude!  Cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the `Delete` issue. In terms of validation, answer my below question and I will fix the same.

Okay, I handled it now properly with an empty item and disabling the selected value on other item.

```js
$(".addItem").on('click', function(e) {
      var parent = $(this).closest('table');
      var lastItem = parent.find(".item:last");
      var newItem = $('<tr class="item"><td><button>Delete</button></td><td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="" id="" class="itemType"><option value="-1"></option><option value="i">Iron</option><option value="c">Copper</option><option value="w">Wood</option></select></td></tr>');
      if(lastItem && lastItem.length > 0) {
  parent.find(".item:last").after(newItem);
        } else {
          parent.append(newItem);
        }
     fixNewSelectOption(newItem);
     handleDeleteAction();
    });


    $(".addCustomer").on('click', function(e) {
      var newCustomer = $('.customer:last').after('<tr class="customer"><td>New Customer</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      var newCart = $('.cart:first').clone(true, true).wrap('td');
      newCart.find('tbody').html("").html('<tr class="item"><td><button>Delete</button></td><td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="" id="" class="itemType"><option value="-1"></option><option value="i">Iron</option><option value="c">Copper</option><option value="w">Wood</option></select></td></tr>');
      $('.customer:last').append(newCart);
      handleDeleteAction();
      e.preventDefault();
    });


$(document).on('click', '.item button', function(){
  if($(this).closest('table').find('.item button').length > 1) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  }
  handleDeleteAction();
});

$(document).on('change', '.itemType', function(){
  fixSelectOption($(this));
});

function handleDeleteAction() {
  $('table.cart').each(function(){
    var cart = $(this);
    var deleteButtons = cart.find('.item button');
    deleteButtons.prop('disabled', deleteButtons.length <= 1);
  });
}

function fixSelectOption(elm) {
  var selected = elm.val();
  var options = elm.find('option[value!="' + selected + '"]');
  var elms = elm.closest('table').find('.itemType').not(elm);
  
  elms.each(function(){
    
    var current = $(this);
    if(current.val() === selected){
        current.val('-1');
      }

    options.each(function(){
       var optValue = $(this).val();
       if(optValue !== '-1' && !$(this).prop('disabled')){
        current.find('option[value="' + optValue + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
       }
     });
      
    if(selected !== '-1'){
      current.find('option[value="' + selected + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
     }
  });
}

function fixNewSelectOption(elm) {
  var elms = elm.closest('table').find('.itemType').not(elm);
  elms.each(function(){
    
    var current = $(this);
    if(current.val() !== '-1'){
        elm.find('option[value="' + current.val() + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
      }
            
  });
}
```

```css
table,
        td,
        th {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
      <title>PO</title>

      <header>
        <form id="panel">
    
        </form>
      </header>
      <section id="I">


    <table id='PO1' class="purchaseOrder">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Cart</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
          <td>Some Name</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>My Address</td>
          <td>Male</td>
          <td>
            <table class='cart'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                  <th>Brand</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Size</th>
                  <th>Color</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr id='item1' class='item'>
                  <td><button disabled>Delete</button></td>
                  <td>Yamaha</td>
                  <td>30</td>
                  <td>Large</td>
                  <td>Black</td>
                  <td>
                    <select id="select" class="itemType">
                        <option value="i">Iron</option>
                        <option value="c">Copper</option>
                        <option value="w">Wood</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan='5'></td>
                  <td>
                    <button class="addItem">Add Item</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='3'></td>
          <td>
            <button class="addCustomer">Add Customer</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </section>
      <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete that respective row on click of any "Delete" button, could you try using this

```
  $(document).on('click', '.item button', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
```

[Here is a Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/yVyGQW)

Another thing I noticed, what are you trying to do in your `$('.itemType').on('change', function()` ? Because as of now all you are doing is literally **checking the value of the selected option to ITSELF** which always obviously will be true.

Comment: Its not working. I have already tried your code. And on the `<select>` tag, please read my **Number 2** problem,

Comment: So this code is working in the Codepen but in your local ?

Comment: Even in Codepen, its not working. The only first item can be deletable.

Comment: Oh ok, since you are adding your row after document ready you need to change that code to the updated one. This should work for the deleting problem of yours

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass an element id which will be deleted from both customer's cart and selected row like this;

```
<tr class="item"><td><button data-id="1">Delete</button></td><td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="" id=""><option value="">Iron</option><option value="">Copper</option><option value="">Wood</option></select></td>
```

jquery part:

```
    $("tr.item button").click(function(){
  var item_to_remove = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var row = $(this).parent().parent();



$.ajax({
    url: "url to cart handler for delete item",
    data: "id="+item_to_remove,
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){
        row.remove();
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("ajax req for delete failed");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the deletion of rows I added checboxes.
[<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/exhCWBBN7yAgN1dEiper/)

#### SNIPPET

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.name,
.brand,
.color {
  width: 10%;
}
.age,
.address,
.pay,
.qty,
.size {
  width: 5%;
}
.cart th:first-of-type {
  width: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>PO</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>
  <section id="I">

    <table id='PO1' class="purchaseOrder">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class='name'>Name</th>
          <th class='age'>Age</th>
          <th class='address'>Address</th>
          <th class='pay'>Pay</th>
          <th>Cart</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
          <td>Jon Doe</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>Earth</td>
          <td>Credit</td>
          <td>
            <table class='cart'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th class='brand'>Brand</th>
                  <th class='qty'>Qty</th>
                  <th class='size'>Size</th>
                  <th class='color'>Color</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr id='item1' class='item'>
                  <td>
                    <input class="chx" name="chx" type="checkbox">
                  </td>
                  <td>New Item</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                    <select name='color'>
                      <option value='black'>Black</option>
                      <option value='white'>White</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="remItem" onclick='remItem(this)'>-</button>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan='3'></td>
                  <td>
                    <button class="addItem" onclick='addItem("itemTemplate", this)'>+</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>


          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='3'></td>
          <td>
            <button class="addCustomer">Add Customer</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>


  </section>
  <footer>
    <template id="cartTemplate">

      <table class='cart'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th class='brand'>Brand</th>
            <th class='qty'>Qty</th>
            <th class='size'>Size</th>
            <th class='color'>Color</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class='item'>
            <td>
              <input class="chx" name="chx" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>New Item</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <select name='color'>
                <option value='black'>Black</option>
                <option value='white'>White</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button class="remItem" onclick='remItem(this)'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td colspan='3'></td>
            <td>
              <button class="addItem" onclick='addItem("itemTemplate",this)'>+</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>

    </template>
    <template id='itemTemplate'>

      <tr class="item">
        <td>
          <input class="chx" name="chx" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>New Item</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <select name="color">
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="white">White</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </template>

  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(".addCustomer").on('click', function(e) {
      var newCustomer = $('.customer:last').after('<tr class="customer"><td>New Customer</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      var newCart = newClone('cartTemplate');
      $('.customer:last').append(newCart);
      e.preventDefault();

    });

    function newClone(id) {
      var template = document.getElementById(id);
      var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
      return clone;
    }

    function addItem(id, origin) {
      var newItem = newClone(id);
      $(origin).closest('table').append(newItem);
    }

    function toggle(origin) {
      var chxList = $(origin).closest('table').find('.chx:checked');
      chkList.click(function() {
        chkList.prop('checked', origin.checked)
      })
    }

    function remItem(origin) {
      var chxList = $(origin).closest('table').find('.chx:checked');
      chxList.each(function(idx, obj) {
        obj.closest('.item').remove();
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: That's awesome men! Nice idea.

Comment: Your'e welcome, sir. Note, you can empty the whole `.cart` without leaving a slot and extra steps trying to delete the  leftover item row.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you got answer on your question, but I couldn't notice some bad patterns in your code. You probably heard for **best practices** phrase and how things needs to be done on right way. By that I want to give one suggestions. Avoid using HTML in Javascript code whenever it is possible because it makes the application less well-structured.

By that I want to introduce you to **templates**.

Example how can we optimize your code (from accepted answer):
Wrap everything form `newItem` variable in `script` tag and put somewhere in your body:

```
<script id="newItem-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
  <tr class="item"><td><button>Delete</button></td>
  <td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
  <select name="" id="" class="itemType"><option value="-1"></option>
  <option value="i">Iron</option><option value="c">Copper</option>
  <option value="w">Wood</option></select></td></tr>
</script>
```

Browser will simply ignore this, until you call `html()` method to return that content.

So instead of this:

```
 var newItem = $('<tr class="item"><td><button>Delete</button></td><td>New item</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><select name="" id="" class="itemType"><option value="-1"></option><option value="i">Iron</option><option value="c">Copper</option><option value="w">Wood</option></select></td></tr>');
```

In your javascript file you will have only this:

```
 var newItem  = $('#newItem-template').html();
```

Here is optimized working code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6y2asvnk/1/)

This is jQuery way to manage with templates, but there is powerful template engines if your project get bigger:
[JavaScript templating engines](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396)